# Is it possible to get access to a controller without declaring it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have a bit of a weird situation which requires me to pass my controllers to my directives via a directive scope variable. This works great as long as there are only one controller in use per route, which is declared in my `$routeProvider`.

But now I have to have 2 controllers in use in the same template, which causes problems because I can't declare my controllers using `ng-controller` because that will throw a routeProvider error since I'm trying to access data from my route resolve. (You can only access route resolve data if you declare the controller in the same route as the resolve, which then makes using `ng-controller` in the template and `controller` in the directive useless to me).

So this is what I want to do:

```
// Declare one controller in the routing
.when('/someroute', {
  controller: 'MyCtrl'
}

// But pass a different controller to my directive that hasn't been declared 
// in either the route, template or directive
<my-directive ctrl="MyOtherCtrl"></my-directive>
```

But my question is, is it possible to access a controller and its functions without declaring the controller as `ng-controller`, `controller` in directive or in route? My far-fetched idea is that there's a service or something that you can inject which holds all of the controllers, but so far I've come up with none.

Comment: You can create the functions declared in your controller in a service so you can access them from every where

Comment: @AlainIb I don't think that would do it either, and since the two controllers are completely separated in terms of logic I wouldn't want to combine the two since I need stuff bound to the scope too.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject th controller by name into your directives controller using $controller.

var someOtherController = $controller('SomeOtherController ',{$scope: $scope});

It's methods would now be available on $scope.  Be careful with this though, things can get hairy quickly.

Comment: I actually just tried this but it too will create the routeProvider error since it seems to run the controller constructor function even though I'm passing a string..

Answer (score 0):

There is a service to get an instance of any controller, use the [$controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller)

in your directive, inject the `$controller` service then use it in your `link` function:

```
myApp.directive("myDirective", function($controller){
  return {
  scope: {
    ctrl: "@"
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    var myNeededCtrl = $controller(scope.ctrl, {$scope: scope, otherDepenciesThatTheControllerNeed: ...});
    myNeededCtrl.doSomething();
  }
 };
});
```

Comment: @Chrillewoodz can you please give us your needed controller code ?